# How do I get common items from 2 object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have 2 object arrays like these:

**Array 1**

```
[{"id":1,"relationship_type_id":"3"},
{"id":2,"relationship_type_id":"2"},
{"id":3,"relationship_type_id":"1"},]
```

**Array 2**

```
[{"relationship_type_id":1,"contributing":"yes"},
{"relationship_type_id":2,"contributing":"no"},
{"relationship_type_id":3,"contributing":"yes"}]
```

How do I find out which `ids` in array 1 has a relationship type that is contributing i.e. contributing == "yes" based on array 2?

The results should look like this:

**Result 1**

```
[{"id":1}, {"id":3}]
```

Or further more, just returning the amount of contributing relationships

**Result 2**

```
contributingRelationship = 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in combination with [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like so.

If `arr2` is particularly big you would benefit from calculating the contributing types first and keeping them in a map for faster retrieval during the filtering of `arr1`.

```js
var arr1 = [{"id":1,"relationship_type_id":"3"},
{"id":2,"relationship_type_id":"2"},
{"id":3,"relationship_type_id":"1"}];

var arr2 = [{"relationship_type_id":1,"contributing":"yes"},
{"relationship_type_id":2,"contributing":"no"},
{"relationship_type_id":3,"contributing":"yes"}];

var contributing = arr1.filter(function(item) {
  // filter based on whether arr2 has corresponding item
  return arr2.some(function(other_item) {
    return other_item.relationship_type_id == item.relationship_type_id && other_item.contributing == "yes";
  });
}).map(function(item) {
  // map into final representation
  return {
    id: item.id
  };
});

console.log(contributing);
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I'm looking for - I always want to avoid writing loops.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
(function(){
    var contributingIds = [];
    var result = [];

    var arr = [
        {"id":1,"relationship_type_id":"3"},
        {"id":2,"relationship_type_id":"2"},
        {"id":3,"relationship_type_id":"1"}
    ];

    var arr2 = [
        {"relationship_type_id":1,"contributing":"yes"},
        {"relationship_type_id":2,"contributing":"no"},
        {"relationship_type_id":3,"contributing":"yes"}
    ];

    arr2.forEach(function(item){
        if(item.contributing === 'yes'){
            contributingIds.push(item.relationship_type_id);
        }
    });

    arr.forEach(function(item){
        if(contributingIds.indexOf(parseInt(item.relationship_type_id, 10)) >= 0){
            result.push(item.id);
        }
    });

    console.log(result);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it this way:

```
var idarray = [{"id":1,"relationship_type_id":"3"},
{"id":2,"relationship_type_id":"2"},
{"id":3,"relationship_type_id":"1"},]; 


var relarray = [{"relationship_type_id":1,"contributing":"yes"},
{"relationship_type_id":2,"contributing":"no"},
{"relationship_type_id":3,"contributing":"yes"}];

var resultArray = [];

for (var counter=0; counter < idarray.length; counter++) {
        for (var relarrayCounter =0; relarrayCounter < relarray.length; relarrayCounter++) {
            if(idarray[counter].relationship_type_id== relarray[relarrayCounter].relationship_type_id) {
               if (relarray[relarrayCounter].contributing == "yes") {
                   var resultObj = {};
                   resultObj.id = idarray[counter].relationship_type_id;
                   resultArray.push(resultObj);
               }
            }

        }
    }
console.log("Result =", resultArray);
console.log("Contributing relationship = ", resultArray.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used two simple foreach loops to go through each set of hashes, looking for a specified input id. I hope you find it useful.

```js
    // initialize the arrays
    var id_to_relation = [{"id":1,"relationship_type_id":"3"},
    {"id":2,"relationship_type_id":"2"},
    {"id":3,"relationship_type_id":"1"}]
    var relation_to_contribute = [{"relationship_type_id":1,"contributing":"yes"},
    {"relationship_type_id":2,"contributing":"no"},
    {"relationship_type_id":3,"contributing":"yes"}]
    
    window.getRelation = function(id)
    {
        var type = [];  // initialize relationship_type_id holder
        var contributing = 0;  // current count of contributing ids
        for (var hash in id_to_relation)
        {
            if (id_to_relation[hash]["id"] == id)
            {
                type.push(parseInt(id_to_relation[hash]["relationship_type_id"]));  // grab the related types
            }
        }
        for (var hash in relation_to_contribute)
        { 
            if (type.indexOf(relation_to_contribute[hash]["relationship_type_id"]) > -1)
            {
                contributing += relation_to_contribute[hash]["contributing"] == "yes" ? 1 : 0;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "contributingRelationship = " + contributing;
    }
```

```html
Enter requested id: <input type="number" id="thisId" />
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="getRelation(document.getElementById('thisId').value)">
  Check id
</button>
<h1>Result</h1>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work.

```
var a = [{"id":1,"relationship_type_id":"3"},
         {"id":2,"relationship_type_id":"2"},
         {"id":3,"relationship_type_id":"1"},];

var b = [{"relationship_type_id":1,"contributing":"yes"},
         {"relationship_type_id":2,"contributing":"no"},
         {"relationship_type_id":3,"contributing":"yes"}];
var arr = [];
for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<a.length;j++){
        if(b[i].contributing == "yes" && a[j].relationship_type_id == b[i].relationship_type_id){
            arr.push({"id" : a[i].id});

        }
    }
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3c5717oh/1/)***.